# putting \textbf{} inside \newcommand

Tags: macros, bold

I use LaTeX mostly for homework assignments. And I would like a faster way to type

```
\noindent\textbf{problem number}
```

Since I do it for every problem and every part of the problem if  it has multiple parts.

I was thinking something like this might work, but it isn't:

```
\newcommand{\HW{}}{\noindent\textbf{}}
```

I've tried with and without the `\textbf` brackets.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper sectioning command like \paragraph or something like this?

Comment: Do you want the problem number to be automatically generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following format:

```
\newcommand{\HW}{\textbf}
```

Note that I haven't captured the argument, since `\textbf` will do this when used as the replacement of `\HW`. Of course, you can capture and pass the argument if needed via

```
\newcommand{\HW}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

The only different between these two definitions would be if you had category code changes within the argument.

Comment: You can add `\noindent` in the definition, if still needed.